# external jsp for a sidebar

Tags: jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

I am working on a website with friends where there is a sidebar (on the left) with the menu points to navigate through the site. the code for the sidebar however, is in the jsp file for every single menu point and I was asking myself, if it is possible to have one jsp file with the sidebar and include this whereever you want the sidebar to appear instead of having the code for the sidebar in every jsp file seperately. If so, are there examples for this? We are using bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a  to include the separate jsp page or you could use a library such as sitemesh to create a template for your site.